# MVC Pulling data from cached or old database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a C# mvc3 application that is using entity framework to pull data from my SQL server database. I discovered that it seemed to be pulling "old" or "cached" data instead of the data that was currently in the DB.

Once I updated the model it seemed to pull the new data.

My question is how do I make sure that I am always pulling "live" data from the database and not getting "cached" or "old" data?

When I ran the following code and checked the value of tblcompanyinfo.companyname it was returning an old company name (different from what was currently in the DB).

Once I updated the model and re-ran it, it returned the current value of company name.

```
private static ApptReminderEntities db = new ApptReminderEntities();
tblCompanyInfo tblcompanyinfo = db.tblCompanyInfoes.SingleOrDefault(t => (t.CompanyID == lCompanyID));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be due to your shared and static `DbContext Instance` i.e.

```
private static ApptReminderEntities db = new ApptReminderEntities();
```

Replace it with using block as below:

```
using(ApptReminderEntities db = new ApptReminderEntities())
{
  tblCompanyInfo tblcompanyinfo = db.tblCompanyInfoes
                              .SingleOrDefault(t => (t.CompanyID == lCompanyID));
}
```

Using `using` statement, you are

- Creating new `ApptReminderEntities` instance each time.
- Doing whatever you want in database.
- Using is automatically closing and disposing your instance.

So, for each trip to database, use `using` so that you will create new instance of your context each time.

Comment: makes sense. I guess I should define an entity for each function instead of each controller and certainly not use "static".

Comment: @Zenacity I would prefer repository pattern instead, so there will be no need to have it in controller. Secondly, if you happen to make any change, it will automatically applied to all controllers.

Comment: Can you explain that please?

Comment: @Zenacity The repository implementation will have a private property like `private ApptReminderEntities db` and then `public Repository(ApptReminderEntities context){this._context = context;}`. You can check nopcommerce source code for more information and code sample.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not creating a new context for each query - you've defined it as static.

You should always create a new `ApptReminderEntities` for each operation you do on the database.

You can use a repository pattern or similar. In my case, every operation I would do

`var employees = new EmployeeRepository().GetEmployees();`

and in the Employee repository constructor, it creates a `new EmployeeEntities()`

This makes it quite easy to unit test too, as I can overload my repository and pass in a dummy context.